# Perfectly normal

Tags: british-english

A British English native speaker translated this sentence into Croatian:

Growing vegetables has always been a normal pursuit in the countryside and in towns.

like this in English:

Growing vegetables has always been a perfectly normal pursuit in the countryside and in towns.

Why "perfectly"?

Comment: It's stylistic. Literary. A cliché. It  makes it all the more normal.

Comment: You can use perfectly to emphasize an adjective or adverb, especially when you think the person you are talking to might doubt what you are saying. THE COLLINS DICTIONARY

Comment: Just checking, you are translating into Croatian or from Croatian?

Comment: first sentence is in english of course, but that sentence is directly translate from Croatian, word by word. In Croatian there is only word "normal", but native translator added word perfectly.

Comment: Lambie, your comment is excelent! How I can vote for you also?

Comment: @IvicaKartelo You can't really vote for it since he abused the system somewhat and answered with a comment, [which is against their purpose](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and circumvents many of the website design mechanisms. If you hover your cursor over his comment, you'll see a triangle that you can use to indicate that it is useful, but he won't gain rep. points. Insist that he makes an answer to that effect, or [wait for somebody else to provide a real answer to similar effect and vote for their answer instead.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/)

Comment: It's perfectly OK to add *perfectly* here and there in perfectly ridiculous places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your translator has a good reason for adding ***perfectly***, as the word *normal* by itself makes me worry if the gardeners are doing unspeakable things to the vegetable. That is an exaggeration, but the word jumps out to my ear as 'protesting too much' (*I am innocent, I was nowhere nearby, and you'll never prove it!*) It sounds like gardening is not normal at all, but someone is arguing that it is. Saying *perfectly normal* makes it flow better.

Personally, I would edit the translation as "**commonplace** **both** in the countryside and in towns."

> The original Croatian: *Uzgajanje  povrća je  bio odvajkada običan  posao ljudi na selu i u gradu.*

Comment: Yes; I'd say that 'perfectly normal' here is a close paraphrase of 'not in any way remarkable' (slight rephrasing might be preferable) whereas 'normal' strongly suggests 'no, it's not abnormal'.